# Generating MultiPoint column from two Point columns without changing number of rows using shapely

Tags: python, shapely, multipoint

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Point
a=Point(1, 1.5)
b=Point(2, 1.5)
c=MultiPoint([a,b])
```

I am trying to create a MultiPoint column from two Point columns. Using the example code above, I can obtain a multipoint c but the data length is doubled, which I cannot use for an entire dataset. I tried different brackets, none has worked.

My dataset has 42 rows and contains columns of centroid_x (Point(a,b)) and centroid_y (Point(a,b)), which are original and destination locations. When I creating a MultiPoint column that combining (centroid_x and centroid_y), it comes out with 84 rows. I tried `list(zip(tuple(a), tuple(b)))`. It solved the row number issues, but couldn't work for MultiPoint. PS: the method I used works fine with LineString.

Comment: Delete a and b at the end?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant by "data length"?

Comment: A multipoint will always be larger than two points, since it needs the count in addition to the vertices. In shapefile it will also contain the bounding box (for two points, effectively doubling the storage).

Comment: My dataset has 42 rows and contains columns of centroid_x (Point(a,b)) and centroid_y (Point(a,b)), which are original and destination locations. When I create a MultiPoint column that combining (centroid_x and centroid_y), it comes out with 84 rows. I am following https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#sankey, to create a sankey plot for my data. The example uses multiPoint with both original and destination in one geometry column.

Comment: Unclear what "your dataset" is? It's a CSV, a Python list you constructed with 2 columns (one for origin, other for destination), a geopandas dataframe, something else? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below a solution with Geopandas

```py
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Point
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# Get a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86],
     'Latitude1': [-33.58, -16.78, -32.45, 3.60, 11.48],
     'Longitude1': [-59.66, -45.91, -68.66, -70.08, -64.86]})

# Create gdf using Latitude, Longitude (hence a first column of Point)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
# Create second column of Point
gdf['geom2'] = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(df.Longitude1, df.Latitude1)]
# Take both previous Point column and convert to MultiPoint
gdf['multi'] = [MultiPoint([x, y]) for x, y in zip(df.geometry, df.geom2)]

# Create new geodataframe with multi colum set as the geopandas geometry column and intermediate Point columns removed
cleaned_gdf = gdf.set_geometry('multi').drop(['geometry', 'geom2'], axis=1)
# If you don't want to drop colum as above, comment above statement and do only the following (commented)
# cleaned_gdf = gdf.set_geometry('multi')
```